# How to render html in script tag vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to render dynamic html in script tag

I'm create a custom data-table component for my project and now i trying to use a column for operations

but I can't assign function to button or more !

```
{
     field: 'operation',
     title: 'Operations',
     template: (e) => {
         return '<button v-on:click="methodFunction">Click</button>';
     }
}
```

please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which library are you using for creating the Data Table component?

You might try something like:

```
{
     field: 'operation',
     title: 'Operations',
     template: Vue.compile('<button v-on:click="methodFunction">Click</button>')
}
```

This will let Vue actually compile the template, during which it goes through the attributes passed.

Note: Vue.compile() returns a render function.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile

Comment: thanks , but its not working too . when i use this , give Vue is not defined error

Comment: Hey I thought it was implicit. Add to the top of the file: `import Vue from 'vue';`